# Populate a GWT CellTable with ValueProxy

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt-celltable

I have a view that contain a cellTable populated by Proxys (type ValueProxy) received from server side using RequestFactory. I can display rows but some problems* occur when i want to update a row via SelectionCell. The same example work when using a real model not proxy using GWT-RPC.

*Plenty of problems occur such as:

1. Take a long time before update.
2. Update is possible 1 time.
3. Remote connection lost.
4. Stack overflow; to increase the stack size, use the -Xss flag at startup (java -Xss1M ...)

Is there a difference between using a real model or proxy in CellTable.

Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: from my own experience, obtaining data from server side might take quite long if you have large dataset, so please add your query and your value proxy definition, for your second issue it will be helpful if you show us your code so we can tell you what you are doing wrong,  for stackoveflow it might be caused if you have really large data, or recursive data, in other hand please provide more details if you want to get correct answer

Comment: Well i think it's not a problem of dataset size because the CellTable can show data with a pager and everything work. The only problem i have is when i want to update a row via Selection cell, i put a log message in getValue method of the column, then i find out an unlimited call of getValue method. I think there is a problem when i populate the CellTable by remote domain (ValueProxy) instead of domain class. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a link to GWT Google Group where you can find my code, i can't put it here, thanks. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/y4dhObvKCC0